# Add new UIBarButtonItem to a UINavigationBar via a segue's destinationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, saslidemenu

I'm using the SASlideMenu component in my app and am using the custom segue to add a new UIBarButtonItem to the destination view controller.  It differs slightly to the default use case in that I'm using the component in the middle of my app rather than starting with it.  The code is:

```
SASlideMenuViewController* source = self.sourceViewController;
SASlideMenuRootViewController* rootController = source.rootController;
UIViewController* destination = self.destinationViewController;

UIButton* menuButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[rootController.leftMenu.slideMenuDataSource configureMenuButton:menuButton];
[menuButton addTarget:rootController action:@selector(doSlideToSide) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UINavigationItem* navigationItem = destination.navigationItem;
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menuButton];
```

But there's no button added to the UINavigationBar in the view controller.

The demo app from SASlideMenu (https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu) has the segue going to a UINavigationController before the UIViewController, and the original code is:

```
SASlideMenuViewController* source = self.sourceViewController;
SASlideMenuRootViewController* rootController = source.rootController;
UINavigationController* destination = self.destinationViewController;

UIButton* menuButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[rootController.leftMenu.slideMenuDataSource configureMenuButton:menuButton];
[menuButton addTarget:rootController action:@selector(doSlideToSide) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UINavigationItem* navigationItem = destination.navigationBar.topItem;
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menuButton];
```

Where in my app the root view controller is accessed via a push segue from another UIViewController so the segue is going straight to a UIViewController.  Can anyone see why this wouldn't be working?